# How do I set up polymorphic relationships using ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

So lets say a recipe has several ingredients of differing amounts.

**Recipe Model**

```
var Recipe = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    ingredients: DS.hasMany('ingredient')
});
```

**Ingredient Model**

```
var Ingredient = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    recipes: DS.hasMany('recipe'),
    // amount?
});
```

So the amount of each ingredient would depend on the recipe. However on its own the ingredient will not have an amount.

How would you go about modeling that data? Right now I am using the `FixtureAdapter` until I finish building the interface.

Using `Ember 1.5.1` and `Ember-Data 1.0.0-beta.7+canary.b45e23ba`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question:

Define the model like so

```
App.Comment = DS.Model.extend({
  message: DS.belongsTo('message', {
    polymorphic: true
  })
});
```

And the property needs an additional property propertyType, defining the relationship type

```
{
  "message": 12,
  "messageType": "post"
}
```

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#polymorphic-relationships

Now to your second question, not sure if polymorphism would be necessary.  I might just include a joining record

```
var RecipeIngredient = DS.Model.extend({
    amount: DS.attr(),
    ingredient: DS.belongsTo('ingredient')
});

var Recipe = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    ingredients: DS.hasMany('recipeIngredient')
});
```

Comment: To be clear, the amount attribute for an ingredient would have a belongsTo relationship with recipe? And in the payload I would also include an amountType?

Comment: Sorry, I answered, then realized I missed the recipe amount portion of your question, updated above.

Comment: using a joining record seems much more straightforward. Did not even think of that